# How can I write jquery for the click to text change ?

Tags: jquery

I have one div namely `<div id="btnYes" runat ="server" >Yes</div>` When I click on the "Yes" div it will be change as "Counted" . And  I have written for jquery for that function . Please anybody help me .....

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnYes").click(function () {
                $('#<%=btnYes.ClientID %>').html("Counted");
                $('#hdnYesNoAnswer').val('1');  
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Replace $('#<%=btnYes.ClientID %>').html("Counted"); with $(this).html('Counted');

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var buttonYes =  $("#btnYes");
            buttonYes.click(function () {
            buttonYes.val('1');

            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: He wants the value of a seperate div to change, and the text of the 'clicked' div to change. This doesnt accomplish either of his desires.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script>
    $( document ).on( 'click', '#btnYes', function()
    {
        $( this ).html( 'Counted' );
        $( '#hdnYesNoAnswer' ).val( '1' );
    });
</script>
```